# Reduction algorithm for reducible finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a finite group $G$ containing $n$ distinct elements $g_i$ with $i=1,2,...,n$, which are written in a matrix representation and satisfy the commutation relation

$$g_ig_j-g_jg_i=\sum_{l}f_{ijl}g_l$$

with some given structure constants $f_{ijl}$.

Furthermore, all elements are self-inverse:

$$g_ig_i=1$$

Provided that the group G is reducible, does a general procedure exist that can be applied to reduce any such finite group into orthogonal irreducible subgroups? If yes, how is it done in practice, or where can I learn how to do it? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What is the minus sign? Like, what does a minus sign on a generic group look like?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned: all $g_i$ are written in matrix representation. I will add that to the question. But, in a sense, the same question goes for the sum over structure constants on the right hand side in regards to "what is a plus sign?". The statement is just that the group is not Abelian. I believe a matrix representation is not absolutely necessary, but makes thinking about these objects simpler.

Comment: In other words, the group has a Lie algebra associated with it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra

Comment: Added self-inverse condition, for simplicity.